# I would like to know the the meaning of the sentence, 'You know all there is to know.'

Tags: meaning

'You know all there is to know.'

There is a sentence like above.
But I don't know the exact meaning of the sentence.
Maybe, I think that the meaning of the sentence is 'what you know is all.'
Am I right? Would you give me the exact meaning of the sentence?

Comment: You really need to do a better job of giving us surrounding context when you ask for meaning of a sentence. This is getting tiring.

Answer (score 1):

Your interpretation might be off by a nuance.  It sounds like your interpretation uses the person's knowledge as the reference point.  The person possesses certain knowledge and coincidentally, there is no knowledge beyond that.

The meaning is the reverse frame of reference.  There is a universe of knowledge and you know all of it.